# Passing parameters to reportviewer's query

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, reportviewer

I have this query on my `typed dataset` that is used to fill my `ReportViewer`

```
SELECT        proj.descricao AS projeto, func.descricao AS funcionalidade, clb.clube AS cliente, ch.descricao
FROM            chamados ch INNER JOIN
                         projetos proj ON ch.projeto = proj.id INNER JOIN
                         funcionalidades func ON ch.funcionalidade = func.id INNER JOIN
                         clubes clb ON ch.clube = clb.id
WHERE        (ch.responsavel = @responsavel) AND (ch.clube = @clube)
```

See the `parameters`  `@responsavel` and `@clube` ? I'd like to now how to pass values for these parameters from `codebehind`. Thanks ! 
Obs: I know how to do this in windowsForms, but with web application, its different and I have no idea how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution just now *-*
You need to work at the `ObjectDataSource1_Selecting` event. I used `Sessions` to pass the values to one webpage to another.
Here is the code:

```
protected void ObjectDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            string usrValue = Session["usrValue"].ToString();
            string usrText = Session["usrText"].ToString();
            string cliente = Session["cliente"].ToString();

            e.InputParameters["responsavel"] = usrValue;
            e.InputParameters["clube"] = cliente;
        }
```